# DB2 VARCHAR column or XML column or other serialization?

Tags: xml, serialization, db2, varchar

Our application need us (DBAs) to build a new table to store lots of data about different transactions.

Across all these transactions, some attributes are the same for all the transactions types, so these attributes/columns will be fully attributed.

There are a lot of attributes that only some types of transactions have, and others don't.

To store all that, we are looking into creating one table, with some columns being fully attributed, and the other unrelated data (between the transactions) would be stored in a VARCHAR (data_area). The application would then retrieve this data and map it using mainframe copybooks. They are ok with this solution.

I'm thinking this would be the simplest way to do it, but would having an XML datatype column (instead of a VARCHAR) be more powerful (for queries, performance, etc.)?

The first piece of data in the XML structure would need to be used to identify the transaction type, then we would map the rest (from the data_area column). So having a XML column would probably mean that we (DBA’s) would be doing the mapping on our side (instead of the application) before returning the data. Unless there is a way to map the XML data using Cobol (on the application side).

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VARCHAR solution is fine if all serialization and processing is going to be handled on the application side.

If you want to do any significant processing of the data on the database side, I would recommend not using serialization at all, but putting the data into appropriately formatted tables.  An XML formatted column is still going to be clunky and inefficient to work with.

I certainly wouldn't go with XML if it means that the mapping is going to be moved from the application to the database.